# Validar campos vazios em arquivo XLSX - (EPPlus) ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xls

Eu estou fazendo a importação de um arquivo XLSX em C#, usando **ExcelPackage**. 
Faço algumas validações na importação Ex: Numérico, texto e se o campo está vazio.

**Obs: Se todas as colunas do meu arquivo estiverem preenchidas a importação é feita com sucesso.**

Umas das necessidades da aplicação é validar se existe campos vazios na planilha.

Exemplo: Em um Range de {A2:C2}.

**Onde A2 é do tipo int, B2 é string e C2 é float**

```
1 |  A2  |  B2   |  C2   |
2 |      | casa1 | 50,8  |
3 |  50  | casa2 | 50,0  |
```

Eu preciso lançar uma Exception informando que o arquivo contém campos vazios.

O problema é que ao fazer a leitura o campo A2 é ignorado, e o campo B2 "Assume" o lugar do A2, i.e, o campo A2 é a primeira célula portanto ela obrigatoriamente que precisa ser lida, mesmo que esteja vazia, e nesse caso lançar a Exception informando que contém campos vazios.

Então minha questão é:
Eu preciso "forçar" a leitura dos campos mesmo que eles estejam vazios, e lançar Exception, caso estejam. **Como faço isso?**

Meu código é esse:

```
public static List<ModularCostCapacitor> ReadFlieAndBuildModularCostsCapacitors(HttpPostedFile upLoad) 
{
// Validando extensão, cabeçalho e colunas
var fileOriginalName = upLoad.FileName;
var fileOriginalExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileOriginalName);

int rowNum = 0;

if (fileOriginalExtension.ToUpper().Equals(FileExtensionXLS) || fileOriginalExtension.ToUpper().Equals(FileExtensionXLSX))
{
    try
    {
        using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(upLoad.InputStream))
        {
            var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            var hasHeader = true;

            int startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;

            for (rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];

                int i = 0;
                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            if (ValidateCellsXLSX(cell.Text))
                            {
                                // ...
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text))
                            {
                                // ...
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (ValidateCellsXLSX(cell.Text))
                            {
                                // ...
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (ValidateCellsXLSX(cell.Text))
                            {
                                // ...
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (ValidateCellsXLSX(cell.Text))
                            {
                                // ...
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (ValidateCellsXLSX(cell.Text))
                            {
                                // ...
                            }
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if (ValidateCellsXLSX(cell.Text))
                            {
                                // ...
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid File");
}
```

}

Código de Validação:

```
public static bool ValidateCellsXLSX(string cell)
{
   Regex regex = new Regex(@"[;!*#&@?()'$~^<>ºª%\{}A-Za-z]");

   string validString = cell.Replace("%", "").Replace("R$", "").Replace("-", "");

   Match match = regex.Match(validString);

   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell))
   {
      throw new Exception("Arquivo contém campos vazios";);
   }
   else if (match.Success)
   {
      throw new Exception("Arquivo contém caracteres inválidos");
    }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Caso ainda necessite da resolução. Eu reduzira o seu método assim.

```
public static List<ModularCostCapacitor> ReadFlieAndBuildModularCostsCapacitors(HttpPostedFile upLoad)
{
    var fileOriginalName = upLoad.FileName;
    var fileOriginalExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileOriginalName);

    if (fileOriginalExtension.ToUpper().Equals(FileExtensionXLSX) || fileOriginalExtension.ToUpper().Equals(FileExtensionXLSX))
    {
        try
        {
            var package = new ExcelPackage(upLoad.InputStream);

            var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

            for (int i = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row; i <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
                {

                    var cellValue = workSheet.Cells[i, j].Text;
                    ValidateCellsXLSX(cellValue);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid File");
    }
}
```

Só uma coisa não compreendi, o que esse método faz com esse tipo de retorno, já que você só faz validação no arquivo. Qualquer dúvida só chamar para o chat. Att.

Comment: Ele faz diversas operações, eu as suprime pois não eram relevantes para a questão =)